# PowerShell - remove first character if a specific character

Tags: powershell

```
 $path = "\path\to\my\file"
```

I want to simply remove the first `\` how do I do that?

I don't want to remove the first character if it's a letter, only if it's `\`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$path = $path.TrimStart("\")
```

Would convert `$path` to `path\to\my\file`

Take note that subsequent leading backlashes would also be removed as well, so if you had `\\\path` it would be reduced to `path`!

Comment: you may want to mention that the `.Trim()` variants trim the _characters as individual chars_ in the parens ... and trim ALL OF THEM. so, your code would trim away **_all_** the leading backslash characters. that is fine when you expect it ... but truly disconcerting when it happens unexpectedly. [*grin*]

Comment: ... as I [noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70171826/archive-folder-without-some-subfolders-and-files-using-powershell/70173927#70173927) while trying to trim `.\` from a relative path when zipping.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the regex `-replace` operator:

```
$path = $path -replace '^\\'
```

This will remove exactly 1 backslash from the start of the string